# Encryption on oracle 8i

Tags: encryption, envdte, oracle8i

I need some kind of DTE in oracle 8i?

Does oracle8i comes with something built in?

Is that even posible? no matter if is a 3rd party solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle tde was introduced in 10g.  I think if you were going to do it in 8i, you might be able to use something from dbms_obfuscation - take a look here: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/DataEncryption.php

Comment: I know, but then i read this http://www.dbasupport.com/oracle/ora8/8iRel2.shtml and in the topic Stored Data Encryption, explain exactly what i need, but i dont know how.